# Public domain countries/prefectures/cities database

Tags: data-request, geospatial, openstreetmap, politics

I need map data as public domain (CC0), so that I can put it excerpts of it into Wikidata.

It does not have to be very detailed, but it should contain country/prefectures/city borders, and also the districts of very big cities like Paris or New York.

OpenStreetMap's data would be perfect (even overkill), but it is under the [ODbL](https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/) license, thus not public domain.

Comment: Doesn't wikidata already have this information? I would've thought they'd have scraped OSM/geonames a long time ago

Comment: @BarryCarter: Wikidata only allows public domain data, and OSM data is not public domain.

Comment: Wikidata uses information from Wikipedia and *that's* not public domain (it's CC-SA or something).

Comment: BTW, Wikidata [allows](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual#Federation) federated queries to [Linked Open Street Map](http://sisinflab.poliba.it/semanticweb/lod/losm/index2.html) and [Linked Geodata](http://linkedgeodata.org/About). There exists also [this project](https://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/talk/2017-May/078029.html).